# How to check all the kwargs that could be passed on to a function

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Let's say I have the following function (constructor in this case),

```
__init__(self, url, **kwargs)
```

How can I check all the possible keyword arguments that could be passed to this function?

Thanks,
Y

Comment: Do you have a list of options you expect?

Comment: check the docs. that's the only reasonable option

Comment: sorry, unless that's a function you're writing and wanting to see if needed options exist? not clear which you mean..

Comment: @mhlester no it's not a function that I'm writing. It's a function that I want to use and I don't have a lit of options I expect. I want to "discover" what list of options are available.

Comment: Then you need to read the documentation or the source code of the tool. `**kwargs` is effectively passing in a `dict`, with whatever keys you've passed.

Comment: if they didn't put it in the function definition, there's no way to enumerate possible legal values without reading the docs (or the code). sometimes, _any_ value is legal - i.e. something like `lxml.Element` where any unknown kwargs are treated as initialization for the new Element.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is checking if the supplied keyword args are all from a valid set of keywords you can use something like:

```
valid_keywords = set(['keyword1', 'keyword2'])
are_keywords_ok = not(set(kwargs) - valid_keywords)
```